# Synchronising time between multiple webservers, database, mobile app, etc

Tags: database, web-services

How is this problem generally solved?

To give some context, I have a single database and multiple processes connected to that database (a mobile api, a custom content management tool and a custom front end website), they all run on different servers. Sometimes it is useful to get delta changes on the database; for instance say I update the database with new data using the content management tool (which then sets some metadata on the data that was changed, specifically its `updated_at` field), and all my mobile apps need a local copy of the database to work. It wouldn't make much sense to redownload the whole db, so it's useful for the app to send its local `last_updated` timestamp and retrieve the subset of fields which were updated since that time. But the mobile api's server's `last_updated` and the database server's `updated_at` are not calculated from the same time source, each server has its own clock.

Is using a time based "freshness indicator" just a dirty mess or is there a robust and efficient way to do it? Or is there a better approach? I'm thinking something like incrementing a version number. What's the best practice for this kind of thing?